# How do I get the type argument of a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

i think this is a simple question but I've searched around and can't seem to find an answer easily.

if you have

```
var list = List<int>();
... fill list ...
```

and you want to get the generic type in list, i realise you could just type:

```
var t = list.FirstOrDefault().GetType();
```

Is there another way to do this via just the list, rather than referring to the enumeration?

Reason is, i have a `System.Data.Linq.Table<TABLE1>` and what i want to do is get the type of `TABLE1` from it.

so:

```
var table = new DataContext().TABLE1s; // this is Table<TABLE1>
var tableType = table.GetType().SomeMethod(); 
// i want tableType to equal TABLE1.GetType()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this to get the entity type of the table

```
var tableType =table.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Type  GetType<T>(Table<T> table)
{
    return typeof(T);
}

var table = new DataContext().TABLE1s; // this is Table<TABLE1>  
var tableType = GetType(table);
```

Comment: well.. didn't think of that! was too caught up in using reflection.. duh!