# How can I get an instantiated generic's parameter type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm appalled I haven't found anything on the internet about this problem, but probably I'm looking for the wrong words. Here is what I need to do.

Suppose I have a generic type: `List<string>` works for the sake of simplicity. How do I get the parameter type (in this case `typeof(string)`)?

Keep in mind that I need to do this from outside the generic class (not inside a class method, which is what I've seen in other SO questions). The bottom line is that I have an instance of a generic type, I need to know both its type AND its parameter type (in the example above, I would like to get both `typeof(List)` AND `typeof(string)`, not anything like `typeof(List<string>)`). Of course, this must be done at runtime.

Thanks to everyone who will reply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the type argument of a generic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549567/how-do-i-get-the-type-argument-of-a-generic-type)

Comment: In fact, Igby. Sorry about the duplicate, I honestly couldn't find it. I looked through the similar questions proposed by the form, but couldn't find anything suitable. Thanks for the answers anyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myList = new List<String>();
var shouldBeString = myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrNull();
var shouldBeGenericList = myList.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx respectively

Comment: I'm approving this one only because of its completeness, but both Harpo's and Osman's answer are equally correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like what you're looking for is [`Type.GetGenericArguments()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx).  You would call it on the `Type` of the instance in question.  It returns an array of `Type` ([to Eric Lippert's chagrin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx)).

Answer (score 4):

```
typeof(List<string>).GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you make your function generic? It will let compiler sort it out for you.

```
void your_func<T>(List<T> lst)
{
    Type list_type = typeof(List<T>);
    Type generic_list_type = typeof(List<>);
    Type generic_argument_type = typeof(T);
    // do what you need     
}
```

You can invoke it like normally:

```
var lst = new List<string>(); 
// ...
obj.your_func(lst);
```

Other option is to use reflection as described in other answers.

Comment: Krizz, I don't know that the generic type will be a List. Actually I need to deal with any type, without any a priori knowledge whether it's a generic type and how many generic parameters it has. This is why I can't use this method.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get it clearly from the question. Then you definitely need to go for reflection as described in other answers.